# Rosserial between two arduinos

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I want to send serial data from one arduino to another based on rosserial. Do i need to run roscore anywhere? Can this work without roscore?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268029/rosserial-between-two-arduinos/) by [elemecro](https://answers.ros.org/users/31397/elemecro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need one PC running roscore and two serial_node instances (one For each Arduino)  in between. Given that you will BE able to communicate between the Arduinos. Direct Connection without PC running roscore ist Not possible

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2017-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [elemecro](https://answers.ros.org/users/31397/elemecro/) on 2017-08-04**:
Thanks for a reply. The problem is: I want to tap a serial signal from a module. I am sure the serial signal is rosserial based. I am giving this signal as an input to arduino mega. I am also running roscore at this end. But no data is received. Kindly give me suggestion if any

**Comment by [elemecro](https://answers.ros.org/users/31397/elemecro/) on 2017-08-04**:
I have also doubt about the topic id. This topic id is transmitted serially. How come another arduino find out the name of topic from this topic id. Can you please give me some other way to tap the serial signals?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-08-04**:
http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial/Overview/Protocol

**Comment by [elemecro](https://answers.ros.org/users/31397/elemecro/) on 2017-08-04**:
the setup is like this : One arduino is sending the serial signal. Another arduino is receiving the serial signal and this arduino is connected with laptop on which roscore is running. My question is how come receiving side arduino know about the topic name which sender arduino has sent?